# JsonConvert.DeserializeObject not working sometimes

Tags: c#, android, json, xamarin, xamarin.android

I'm trying to Deserialize some json using `JsonConver.DeserializeObject`. however it's not working on some json from the api I'm using. here is a link that does not work: https://api.pokemontcg.io/v1/cards?setCode=smp

and here is a link that does work. https://api.pokemontcg.io/v1/cards?setCode=sm2

I'm not sure why it sometimes works and sometimes not. The data that comes out of it is very similar to each other, just different cards.
Here is the code:

```
public static async Task<T> GetDataAsync<T>(this HttpClient client, string address, string querystring)
            where T : class
        {
            var uri = address;

            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(querystring))
            {
                uri += querystring;
            }

            var httpMessage = await client.GetStringAsync(uri);
            var jsonObject = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<T>(httpMessage);

            return jsonObject;
        }
```

Now my card class

```
namespace CardAppReal.Lib.Models
{
    public class Card
    {
        public string id { get; set; }
        public string name { get; set; }
        public string imageUrl { get; set; }
        public string imageUrlHiRes { get; set; }
        public string supertype { get; set; }   // if pokemon, trainer or energy
        public string setcode { get; set; }
        public int number { get; set; }
        public string set { get; set; }

    }
}
```

With a root

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using CardAppReal.Lib.Models;

namespace CardAppReal.Lib.Entities
{
    public class RootCard
    {
        public List<Card> cards { get; set; }
    }
}
```

If u could help me out I would find it amazing.

Comment: When it fails, does it give you an exception or error message?

Comment: @Jason no it does not, it just leaves my jsonObject empty.

Comment: I'd suggest that you carefully compare a working result to a non-working one and identify what the differences are.

Comment: I would log what json is deserializing to an empty object

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have tested your json.

this is the Model

```
namespace Test
{
public class Attack
    {
        public List<string> cost { get; set; }
        public string name { get; set; }
        public string text { get; set; }
        public string damage { get; set; }
        public int convertedEnergyCost { get; set; }
    }

    public class Weakness
    {
        public string type { get; set; }
        public string value { get; set; }
    }

    public class Resistance
    {
        public string type { get; set; }
        public string value { get; set; }
    }

    public class Ability
    {
        public string name { get; set; }
        public string text { get; set; }
        public string type { get; set; }
    }

    public class Card
    {
        public string id { get; set; }
        public string name { get; set; }
        public int nationalPokedexNumber { get; set; }
        public string imageUrl { get; set; }
        public string imageUrlHiRes { get; set; }
        public string subtype { get; set; }
        public string supertype { get; set; }
        public string hp { get; set; }
        public List<string> retreatCost { get; set; }
        public string number { get; set; }
        public string artist { get; set; }
        public string rarity { get; set; }
        public string series { get; set; }
        public string set { get; set; }
        public string setCode { get; set; }
        public List<string> types { get; set; }
        public List<Attack> attacks { get; set; }
        public List<Weakness> weaknesses { get; set; }
        public List<Resistance> resistances { get; set; }
        public string evolvesFrom { get; set; }
        public Ability ability { get; set; }
        public List<string> text { get; set; }
    }

    public class RootObject
    {
        public List<Card> cards { get; set; }

    }
}
```

And this is how I call the Deserialize

```
RootObject root = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObject>(RootObject.WRONG_JSON);
```

(NB WRONG_JSON is your json string...)

[image: this is the result]

Comment: I see my problem. I used a int for the number. While it should be a string. The name decieved me.

Comment: Is it okay to skip some unnecessary attributes from Model? Will it able to deserialize  json?

Comment: You can choose what you want deserialize. Usually JsonIgnore attribute is a good solution